# How can I use numpy.sum to output sum as 2d array without a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to get the sum of each teams score in each round, currently I am able to get the sum of each teams scores from round 1.

#### Current Input

```py
scores = np.array([
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12], #Round 1
    [11, 3, 9, 2, 3, 5, 10]] # Round 2
)

teams = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4]])

np.sum(np.take(scores, teams), axis=1)
```

This outputs the correct sum for each team in the round 1

```
array([ 5,  7, 25])
```

Is there a way to make it output the sum for each team in each round without using a for loop?

##### Desired Output

```
array([[ 5,  7, 25], [23, 14, 18]])
```

Comment: the rows in teams are the teams so each team has 3 players. The rows in scores are the scores of each player by index so player 0's score in Round 1 was 1 `scores[0][0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `axis=1` to `np.take`, and then sum on axis `2`:

```
>>> np.take(scores, teams, axis=1).sum(axis=2)
array([[ 5,  7, 25],
       [23, 14, 18]])
```

Comment: This works, I was under the impression that removing a for loop would speed up my code but it seems just a for loop and indexing into scores is faster when testing with 100,000 teams and 10,000 scores `scores = np.random.rand(10_000,100)` `teams = np.array([random.sample(list(range(100)), 8) for _ in range(100_000)])`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify an axis, so `take`, as documented, works with the flattened array:

```
In [216]: np.take(scores.ravel(),teams)
Out[216]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2],
       [ 2,  2,  3],
       [12,  8,  5]])
```

Using `teams` to index the columns:

```
In [220]: scores[:,teams]
Out[220]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  2],
        [ 2,  2,  3],
        [12,  8,  5]],

       [[11,  3,  9],
        [ 3,  9,  2],
        [10,  5,  3]]])
```

and summing:

```
In [221]: scores[:,teams].sum(axis=2)
Out[221]: 
array([[ 5,  7, 25],
       [23, 14, 18]])
```

Comment: This solution works, but when run with larger arrays it becomes very slow, Im guessing due to memory issues?